# Approximation of $f \in L^1_{loc}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

I am trying to prove the following statement: If $\Omega$ open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f \in L^1_{loc}(\Omega)$ (a set of all functions whose integrals on compact sets exist) and $\int_{\Omega}f\cdot g dx=0$ for all $g\in C^{\infty}_0(\Omega)$ than: $f=0$ almost everywhere. I was trying some regularization of f but unsuccessfully and I am not sure if that is a good idea.

Comment: You're using that $C_0^\infty(\Omega)$ is dense in the dual space and Hahn-Banach.

Comment: Can you expand a little your idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of regularizing $f$, let $\chi_{S}$ be a the characteristic function of any bounded Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then regularize $g_{\epsilon}=\chi_{S}\star \varphi_{\epsilon}$ so that it is (a) compactly supported (b) uniformly bounded and (c) converges pointwise a.e. to $\chi_{S}$ as $\epsilon \downarrow 0$ along a subsequence. Conclude that $\int_{S}f\,ds=0$ for all bounded Borel subsets $S$ by the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Am I right that it is enought to show the resoult only for compact subsets of $\Omega$ instead of Borel ones ?

Comment: Are you asking if it is enough to show that $\int_{S}f\,dx=0$ for all compact subsets $S$ of $\Omega$?

Comment: yes, that is not true ?